# Multiple Selenium parametrized webtests using Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, junit, webdriver

Seems I'm not enough smart to figure it out by myself - I have Eclipse Kepler installed, with jUnit 4.11, selenium-java 2.41 and a mozilla plugin for selenium.

Everything is great, everything (at this moment) works great.
My aim is to create a test, that repeats n times, everytime using the second String[] array element. For example:

```
`@Test
public void testGoogleSearch() throws Exception {
 driver.get(baseUrl);
 driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("Find me"); // Input text from String array here
 driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).click();

 try {
     assertEquals("Find me", driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).getAttribute("value"));
 } catch (Error e) {
     verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
 }
}`
```

As you can see, there is static "Find me" text. I want, that my test will run 5 times, each time input changes to early defined array elements.

How can i do that? Any clues? I've read about parametrized testing, but does it really is that i need? I didn't found anything there about multiple repeating.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read about parametrized testing, but does it really is that i
>   need?

Yes, it is exactly what you need. [Parameterized.class](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class GoogleSearchClass {

    private String searchString;
    private String expectedString;
    public GoogleSearchClass (String srch, String expect){
        searchString = srch;
        expectedString = expect;
    }


    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {"search1", "expected1"}, {"search2", "expected2"}, {"search3", "expected3"}
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testGoogleSearch() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys(searchString); // Input text from String array here
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).click();

        try {
         //   Assert.assertEquals(expectedString, driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).getAttribute("value"));
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... so i suppose that @..Parameters automatically passes data to @Test? 
By the way, what for is dsgsd() method? is it meant as a constructor?

Comment: Parameterized.class will loop thru all the parameters you have in the collection. Try it out. And sry for the type, fixed it.

Comment: Yep, thats the solution! 
Thank you... Seems that 11-hour continious learning made a peanut of my brain. Accepting answer =)